# Send Get with jQuery with spaces

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with a word count using the jQuery. The method is working as soon as I click space it will stop.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="essay_content_area" name="essay_content" onkeydown="words();"></textarea>
<td>Number of words: <div id="othman"></div></td>
```

jQuery:

```
function words(content)
{
    var f = $("#essay_content_area").val()
    $('#othman').load('wordcount.php?content='+f);
}
```

PHP file:

```
if(isset($_GET['content']))
{
        echo $_GET['content']; // if it works I will send this variable to a function to calculate the words 
}
```

the script shows the content until I click space. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to url-encode the value before sending it over to your PHP script as the value of a `GET` parameter.  Consider this:

```
function words(content)
{
    var f = $("#essay_content_area").val()
    $('#othman').load('wordcount.php?content=' + encodeURIComponent(f));
}
```

Comment: Just one thing to have in mind, there are often a length limitation for get strings, so it could be a good idea to check your server settings or maybe send it as post. Post's limitation are usual higher.

Comment: @NiclasLarsson good point.  In fact, I don't think there is a length limitation on POST, at least not with `multipart` encoding.

Comment: @NiclasLarsson Thank you .. I found out it only takes 5000 characters. Do you know the approach to change it to `post` method?

Comment: I'm not very good att jquery, but it looks like if you add the data as a second parameter in the load function as an object, the data will be sent as post: `$('#othman').load('wordcount.php', {content: encodeURIComponent(f)});`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need php to count the words you can use JS, something like this:

```
function words(content)
{
   // Get number of words.
   var words = content.split(" ").length;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I have a function to calculate the words like MS words. this function would give me different count from the MS words function that I had programmed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to url encode your variable before you send it (space is not a valid url character):

```
function words(content)
{
    var f = encodeURIComponent($("#essay_content_area").val());
    $('#othman').load('wordcount.php?content='+f);
}
```